# how to change Text to Speech voice and how to insert characters into char array

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, winapi, text-to-speech

I need to change the voice of the **Text To Speech** engine. When a menu is selected (`ID_SPEAK_PLAY`), I get the text of an edit box and simply read it.

My situation can be solved in two ways :

1. insert the **XML** code at the begining of `ptrData` without using `strncat` or other functions that involve creating other `wchar_t*` buffers (memory issues ). `StringCchPrintf` is not working.
2. change the voice in some other way that i don't know.

Here is my code :

```
    case ID_SPEAK_PLAY:
             text_size = SendMessage(h_edit, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
             text_size += 100;
             ptrData = new wchar_t[text_size];
             SendMessage(h_edit, WM_GETTEXT, text_size, (LPARAM)ptrData);
             StringCchPrintf(ptrData, text_size, L"<voice required = \"Gender=Female;Age=Teen\"> %s", ptrData);
             pVoice->Speak(ptrData, SPF_ASYNC | SPF_IS_XML, NULL);
             delete [] ptrData;
             break;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> StringCchPrintf is not working.

That is because you ignored the warning in the documentation:

> **Behavior is undefined** if the strings pointed to by pszDest, pszFormat, or any argument strings overlap.

You are specifying `ptrData` as both `pszDest` and an argument string, so your code has **undefined behavior**.  You must use separate buffers when using `StringCchPrintf()`:

```
case ID_SPEAK_PLAY:
         text_size = SendMessage(h_edit, WM_GETTEXTLENGTHW, 0, 0) + 1;
         ptrData = new wchar_t[text_size];
         SendMessage(h_edit, WM_GETTEXTW, text_size, (LPARAM)ptrData);
         speak_size = text_size + 100;
         speakData = new wchar_t[speak_size];
         StringCchPrintf(speakData, speak_size, L"<voice required = \"Gender=Female;Age=Teen\"> %s", ptrData);
         pVoice->Speak(speakData, SPF_ASYNC | SPF_IS_XML, NULL);
         delete [] speakData;
         delete [] ptrData;
         break;
```

Alternatively, just skip `StringCchPrintf()` and let `WM_GETTEXT` populate your single buffer directly:

```
case ID_SPEAK_PLAY:
{
         const wchar_t *xml = L"<voice required = \"Gender=Female;Age=Teen\"> ";
         const int xml_size = lstrlenW(xml);
         text_size = SendMessage(h_edit, WM_GETTEXTLENGTHW, 0, 0);
         ptrData = new wchar_t[text_size + xml_size + 1];
         lstrcpyW(ptrData, xml);
         SendMessage(h_edit, WM_GETTEXTW, text_size+1, (LPARAM)(ptrData+xml_size));
         pVoice->Speak(ptrData, SPF_ASYNC | SPF_IS_XML, NULL);
         delete [] ptrData;
         break;
}
```

> change the voice in some other way that i don't know.

Instead of inserting XML in front of your text, you can call the [`ISpVoice::SetVoice()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms719807.aspx) method before calling `ISpVoice::Speak()`. Use [`SpEnumTokens()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717535.aspx) to know which voices are installed, or use [`SpFindBestToken()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717543.aspx) to search for a voice that matches the criteria you need.

Comment: Thank you I used `SpEnumTokens()` and `ISpVoice::SetVoice()` and its a better alternative than **XML**

Comment: now I am going to get Greedy and ask how to get more voices beside English US (Microsoft David and Zira ) Englsh UK (Microsoft Hazel) ?. I am interest in arabic language . thanks four your help

Comment: You buy them.  A bit of googling suggests that Sakhr is your best bet.